# 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax near ''

Tags: mysql, sql

> 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
> SELECT a.* FROM `ws_items` a WHERE 1 AND `enabled`=1 AND `visible`=1 ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 0,

I searched the website, but none matches my query. I have no idea on how to use mysql, but I really need to solve this problem...
 Maybe someone here knows the solution

```
 if ($params["page_name"]=="index")
        {

            $filter = "";
            if ($_SESSION['user_data']['type']!="admin")
            {
                $filter = " AND `enabled`=1 AND `visible`=1 ";
            }

            $sql = "SELECT a.* FROM 
            `".DB_PREFIX."items` a WHERE 1 $filter 
            ORDER BY `created` DESC 
            LIMIT ".($_SESSION['itemsPerPage']*($page-1)).",".$_SESSION['itemsPerPage'];

            $items = $DB->getAll($sql); 
            for($i=0; $i<count($items); $i++)
            {
                $items[$i][third] = "";

                $items[$i][thumb_rating] = rating_bar($items[$i]['id'], '5', 'static');
                if($i%3==2)
                    $items[$i][third] = 'style="margin-right:0;"';
            }

            $smarty->assign("items", $items);

            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(a.id) as `total` FROM 
            `".DB_PREFIX."items` a WHERE 1 $filter 
            ";

            $items = $DB->get($sql);
            $total = $items['total'];

            $smarty->assign("pagination", $DB->show_pagination($total, $page, $_SESSION['itemsPerPage']));

            $output = $this->display(__FILE__, 'latestwallpapers.tpl');
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: I'd say get rid of the `1 AND` at the beginning of the where clause but I'm not sure

Comment: Using string concatenation to compose queries that contain user data is a recipe for a really bad day in your future. Are you sure you have to do it this way? [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) are no fun at all.

Comment: It seems your query lacks the offset: `DESC LIMIT 0,`. Of course evaluates 1 to true in a boolean context: _MySQL evaluates any nonzero, non-NULL value to TRUE._ see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: Are you sure that $_SESSION['itemsPerPage'] has a value?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a safe way of creating `$filter` that prevents SQL injection, then try changing it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.* FROM 
       `".DB_PREFIX."items` a WHERE 1=1 $filter 
       ORDER BY `created` DESC 
       LIMIT ".($_SESSION['itemsPerPage']*($page-1)).",".($_SESSION['itemsPerPage']+0);
```

If your query ends with `LIMIT 0` then it won't return any rows and if it ends `LIMIT 0,` then it is indeed syntactically incorrect.

You need to make sure that you have a value for the offset.

I have tweaked the query to add zero to the offset, so it should now end with `LIMIT 0,0` but beware this won't return any rows. I guess your session variable doesn't have a value.

Why not try `var_dump($_SESSION['itemsPerPage']);` as suggested by @VMai?

**EDIT:** I bet you `$_SESSION['itemsPerPage']` is set after the first time you reference it. Hence the first time you load the page it fails, then when you refresh, that value is there and it works.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['itemsPerPage']);` would be a good idea for the OP. And a good hint your yours that `LIMIT 0` in a valid statement would not make sense.

Comment: I do not know why it ends with LIMIT 0 . I tried using your code, but it is the same error.

Comment: Indeed, your tweaked code will remove the error from showing, but will return no rows. The weird thing is that if I press refresh, the rows will show and no error will be displayed (that happened before using your code too - first time it gives the error, after refreshing it works normally. If I close the brwoser and open it again, it will show the error. Refreshing will solve it.)

Comment: That's because you are setting the session variable after you are trying to use it!

Comment: I bet you `$_SESSION['itemsPerPage']` is set after the first time you reference it. Hence the first time you load the page it fails, then when you refresh, that value is there and it works.

Comment: Great, now that might be the problem, but I'm sorry I have to ask again...how can I solve it?

Comment: Simply check where in your code `$_SESSION['itemsPerPage']` is being set (the code is in there, so search for it using your editor) and make sure you call it earlier on (before you call this routine).

Comment: Please check my question, it has all the code. Maybe you can tell me what to modify. I tried to move it a bit, but no luck...

Comment: Your question doesn't have all of the code. The session variable could be set anywhere. Search through the code using some kind of tool.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that

```
$_SESSION['itemsPerPage']
```

is null and when multiplying by `$page - 1` is being converted to 0 so it's evaluating to 0 in the query, but when concatenated at the end is just producing nothing which is causing the syntax error in the LIMIT clause:

```
DESC LIMIT 0,
```

Comment: I don't know, did you edit your answer before or after I posted mine? I'm on my phone so it took me a little while to write my answer.

Comment: Five minutes before. But I know exactly what you mean. I sometimes try to answer on my phone and it's very painful! :-)

Comment: Well I feel my answer is a little more succinct. Yours proposes a solution that doesn't actually help at all if the session variable is null.